# In SceneKit clipping one object geometry when intersecting with another

Tags: opengl, scenekit

I'm trying to determine how I can clip one object with another.

[image: Plane slicing sphere]

The sphere is stationary, but the plane moves around the scene and should clip the sphere as it passes through it. Everything is working, up to the part where the plane clips the sphere.

Can SceneKit accomplish this without resorting to a custom `SCNProgram` shader?

### Progress Update

#### Calculate the plane equation

Not 100% certain this is exactly correct. In broad strokes - I have a 'fake' cutting plane that I keep around (not strictly necessary), extract the vertices, apply the affine transform, and try to derive the plane equation from, finally passing the value to the vertex shader.

```
let planeSources = _planeNode?.geometry?.geometrySourcesForSemantic(SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex)
if let planeSource = planeSources?.first {
    let stride = planeSource.dataStride
    let offset = planeSource.dataOffset
    let componentsPerVector = planeSource.componentsPerVector
    let bytesPerVector = componentsPerVector * planeSource.bytesPerComponent

    let vectors = [SCNVector3](count: planeSource.vectorCount, repeatedValue: SCNVector3Zero)
    let vertices = vectors.enumerate().map({
        (index: Int, _) -> SCNVector3 in
        var vectorData = [Float](count: componentsPerVector, repeatedValue: 0)
        let byteRange = NSMakeRange(index * stride + offset, bytesPerVector)
        planeSource.data.getBytes(&vectorData, range: byteRange)
        return SCNVector3Make(vectorData[0], vectorData[1], vectorData[2])
    })

    let mat4Transform = SCNMatrix4ToMat4(transform)
    let transformedVertices = vertices.map({
        (vertex: SCNVector3) -> vector_float3 in
        let float4Vector = SCNVector4ToFloat4(vertex.to4(1.0))
        let transformedVertex = matrix_multiply(mat4Transform, float4Vector)
        return vector3(transformedVertex.x, transformedVertex.y, transformedVertex.z)
    })

    if transformedVertices.count >= 3 {
        let vertex0 = transformedVertices[0]
        let vertex1 = transformedVertices[1]
        let vertex2 = transformedVertices[2]

        let v1v0 = vertex1 - vertex0
        let v2v0 = vertex2 - vertex0
        let normal = vector_cross(v1v0, v2v0)
        let distance = vector_dot(normal, vertex0)
        let planeEquation = -1.0 * vector4(normal, distance)
        let planeEquationValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4FromFloat4(planeEquation))

        self._heartNode?.geometry?.setValue(planeEquationValue, forKey: "plane_equation")
    }
}
```

#### Vertex shader snippet

```
varying float clipFragment;

#pragma body
uniform vec4 plane_equation;

float distance = dot(_geometry.position.xyz, plane_equation.xyz) + plane_equation.w;
if (distance <= 0.0) {
    clipFragment = 1.0; // Discard fragment
} else {
    clipFragment = 0.0; // Keep fragment
}
```

This is working in so far that the object is clipped based upon rotation of the plane in space, but not in the sense that the plane is touching.

[image: Sliced Heart]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but: your clipping plane is infinite, so is your actual plane (with the MVM) also infinite? In that case, I'd suggest multiplying a vec3(0,1,0) or vec3(0,0,1) with a mat3(MVM) of the plane to get the normal, multiplying vec4(0,0,0,1) with MVM to get the origin of the plane, and then using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html to convert this into the plane equation. I'm posting this as a comment because I'm not very mathy and this could be very wrong.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer So do you need the clip plane's equation in the sphere's object space coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm should be the following (described abstractly, as I'm not familiar with that API):

1. Let `Mi` be the inverted Model matrix of the sphere (any vector algebra API seems to provide some way to calculate matrix inversion);
2. Let `Ax+By+Cz+D=0` be an equation of the clipping plane (CP) in world coordinates (I guess you meant, that the plane equation is described in world space);
3. Multiplication `transpose(invert(mat3_from_mat4(Mi)))*(A,B,C)` produces `N'=(A',B',C')`;
4. Let `P` be some point, belonging to CP. Example: `P=(0,0,-D/C)`, provided, that C is not zero;
5. Multiplication `Mi*(P.x,P.y,P.z,1.0)` produces `P'=(A0',B0',C0',W0')`;
6. Getting rid of *w*-component in `P'` produces `P"=(A0'/W0',B0'/W0',C0'/W0')=(A0",B0",C0")`, which is a CP's point in sphere's object space coordinates;
7. The desired equation is `A'x+B'y+C'z-dot(N',P")=0`.

EDIT: If the plane is defined in its local space, and the corresponding MVMs are defined for both sphere and plane, then the algorithm is a bit different. Instead `P` should be first transformed to the common eye space using plane's MVM, and then the obtained values should be transformed using sphere's inversed MVM. `N` should be transformed by premultiplying with `transpose(mat3_from_mat4(MVM(Sphere)))*transpose(invert(mat3_from_mat4(MVM(Plane))))`.

Comment: I meant normalization in sense of getting rid of homogenous coordinates.

Comment: Also note, that `modelMatrix` is used instead of `modelViewMatrix`, that I noticed on gist.

Comment: And what are the values of model matrix?

Answer (score 0):

### The Plan in Swifty Pseudocode

The most simplistic scenario is to measure the distance from the plane that represents the marker and the vertex that is about to get rendered.

#### Compute the plane equation

```
// Using something like SKLinearAlgebra for cross(), dot(), and to4()
// The marker vertices - these need to be counter-clockwise?
let origin = vertices[0]
let vector1 = vertices[1]
let vector2 = vertices[2]
let normal = SCNVector3.cross(vector1, vector2)
let distance = SCNVector3.dot(normal, vector0)

let planeEquation = normal.to4(distance)
```

#### Calculate the signed distance - in the vertex shader

```
// Given the plane equation
let distance = planeEquation.x * vertex.x + 
               planeEquation.y * vertex.y +
               planeEquation.z * vertex.z + 
               w
```

If the distance is less than or equal to zero the fragment is discarded otherwise do what you normally do.